# Python - Counting frequency of strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how to count the frequency of strings in a list and use them.

```
example list: fruits = (['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'mango'])
def fruitcounter():
    from collections import Counter
    a = Counter(fruits)
    return(a)
Counter({'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'mango': 1})
```

The fruits list is random.
Is there any way to use these numbers and assign them so I can do other calculations like the percentage of apples in the list?

Comment: Like `counts = Counter(fruits)` and then use `counts['mango']` or `counts['apple']`?

Comment: You can treat a `Counter` object just like any `dict` - i.e. if you assign it to a variable: `c = fruitcounter()` you can now use `c['apple']` etc.

Comment: You have frequency and you have list size so why can't you calculate percentqage?

Comment: Thanks for quick comments. The fruits list is not known, that is just an example. It could be 5 strings in the list, could be any number, and it could have different fruits such as pineapple.

Comment: Response to @Jarmod, I cannot use counts['mango'] or counts['apple'] because I maybe don't know what fruit will be in my list.

Comment: Response to @Błotosmętek, I cannot use c['apple'] for the same reason above.

Comment: @TracyWang You can use `c[variable]` where `variable` contains the fruit you're interested in at any particular time.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary comprehension that divides all the counts by the length of the list.

```
a = Counter(fruits)
percents = {fruit: count/len(fruits)*100 for fruit, count in a.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'apple': 40, 'banana': 40, 'mango': 20}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ether user `len(fruits)` or sum up the counter values to get the amount of total fruits:

```
from collections import Counter

fruits = (['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple'])
counts = Counter(fruits)
totals = sum(counts.values())

bananaPercent = 100/totals*counts['banana']
print('You got %s percent bananas!' % bananaPercent)
```

Output:

```
You got 50 percent bananas!
```

Edit, in case you dont know the fruits:

```
from collections import Counter

fruits = (['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple'])
counts = Counter(fruits)
totals = sum(counts.values())

for k in counts.keys():
    kPercent = 100/totals*counts[k]
    print('%ss make %s percent!' % (k, kPercent))
```

Output:

```
apples make 50 percent!
bananas make 50 percent!
```

Comment: How is `len(fruits)` different than `sum(counts.values())`?

Comment: I guess `len(...)`, it will be faster :)

Comment: @Maurice Meyer. For the output, is there any way to get "apples make 50 percent and bananas make 50 percent" on the same line?

Comment: Telling the print function what you want at the *end* of the print call will accomplish something like what you're looking for.

```print('%ss make %s percent!' % (k, kPercent), end= ' ')```

This replaces the default newline with a space at the end out the output.

Answer (score 0):

to calculate the percentage of apples in the list you could access the frequency of the apples and divide by the total amount of fruits like this:

```
from collections import Counter
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'mango']

c = Counter({'apple': 2, 'banana': 2, 'mango': 1})
apple_percentage = 100 * c['apple']/len(fruits)
print(f'{apple_percentage}%')
```

output:

```
40.0%
```

Comment: Does the OP say that he wants to assign to the Counter ? seems more like a question about how to access the frequencies